# How can I encrypt my home folder after a Ubuntu Server 13.10 install?

Tags: command-line, server, encryption, home-directory

I would like to know the command(s) to enable the encryption of my home directory **after** installing a *Ubuntu Server* with a release version of 13.10.

**Note:** This is a Ubuntu Server install, not a Desktop install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sudo `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup`

For more info [How To encrypt Home Folder](http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/)

Comment: welcome man again